# Saving an empty dataframe in azure blov with .csv extension

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Hi all I'm stuck at one place I have a dataframe say like:

```
col1,col2
a,0
c,0
B,0
b,0
```

I'm filtering it and in some situation I may get an empty resultant dataframe like:

```
 val tempDf:DataFrame= df.filter(expr("col2=1"))
```

which results:

```
+---------+---------+
|Col1     |Col2     |
+---------+---------+
+---------+---------+
```

when I'm saving it to azure blob

```
df.coalesce(1).write.option("header", "true").mode("overwrite").format("csv").save(location)
```

it giving me error

```
Datasource does not support writing empty or nested empty schemas.
Please make sure the data schema has at least one or more column(s)
```

I know it is not possible to save an empty dataframe to azure blob directly. But there must be some way to do this.
I have gone through some question [like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56946600/in-spark-how-to-write-header-in-a-file-if-there-is-no-row-in-a-dataframe) but i'm not getting but there have been used local file sytem for processing .

Is there any way to save a dataframe when there is empty rows and what i have thought to insert one row with null values for each column but it will hamper my next operation becauese this output will be used for the next processing.

**I'm using version for spark is 2.4**
Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is known bug in spark [SPARK-26208](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-26208) fixed in 3.0.0 version. If you can't migrate to spark 3.0 you can write your own class extending `CSVFileFormat`:

```
package path.to.your.package

import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.InternalRow
import org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat
import org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.{OutputWriter, OutputWriterFactory}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType

class CustomCSVFileFormat extends CSVFileFormat with Serializable {

  override def shortName(): String = CustomCSVFileFormat.EMPTY_CSV_WRITER_NAME

  override def prepareWrite(
                             sparkSession: SparkSession,
                             job: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job,
                             options: Map[String, String],
                             dataSchema: StructType): OutputWriterFactory = {
    val writerFactory = super.prepareWrite(sparkSession, job, options, dataSchema)
    new OutputWriterFactory {
      override def newInstance(
                                path: String,
                                dataSchema: StructType,
                                context: TaskAttemptContext): OutputWriter = {
        /* This custom writer is wrapper for common CsvOutputWriter.
         Custom writer checks if options contains:  header -> true, then writing empty row for print headers to file
         If headers printed common writer skip empty rows always and this doesn't affect to further writing */
        val outputWriter = writerFactory.newInstance(path, dataSchema, context)
        if (options.get("header").exists(_.toBoolean)) {
          outputWriter.write(InternalRow.empty)
        }
        outputWriter
      }

      override def getFileExtension(context: TaskAttemptContext): String = {
        writerFactory.getFileExtension(context)
      }
    }
  }
}

object CustomCSVFileFormat {
  val CUSTOM_CSV_WRITER_NAME = "customCSV"
}
```

and add file

`src/main/resources/META-INF/services/org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister`

with content:

`path.to.your.package.CustomCSVFileFormat`

and use your custom format by short name:

```
df.coalesce(1)
  .write
  .option("header", "true")
  .mode("overwrite")
  .format(CustomCSVFileFormat.CUSTOM_CSV_WRITER_NAME)
  .save(location)
```